# org-mode XeLaTeX export to pdf: define font color for different structure levels

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf

I would like to set the colors for a pdf export of an org-mode file based on the structural elements. That is something like

```
* This Headline Should Be Blue
** This subheadline should be green
   - List items should be black
Plain text should be black
```

Currently, I can modify the font and font color for the entire exported document with the following:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER:\usepackage{fontspec}
#+LATEX_HEADER:\setmainfont[Color=Green]{Fira Sans}
#+LATEX_HEADER:\setsansfont[Color=Green]{Fira Sans}
```

And I can set the color for a specific region with something like

```
\addfontfeature{Color=red} this part is red \addfontfeature{Color=black} and now back to black
```

But I'd like to define consistent rules across the document so I don't have to keep manually switching back and forth between colors.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{titlesec}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titleformat*{\section}{\color{blue}}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titleformat*{\subsection}{\color{green}}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titleformat*{\paragraph}{\color{black}}
```

Comment: What's the question? And why/how does it serve as an answer for the OP's question?

Comment: I've made some edits to more directly answer the question.

Comment: Thanks. This looks to work for \section and \paragraph, but the \subsection coloring is also black. (The titlesec package also kinda messes with some other formatting, but that's a separate issue)

Comment: Hmm - not sure what's going on there, sorry.

Comment: This worked for me when I added #+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xcolor}